# Trying to Create Multi Level header from a python dataframe - tried Multiindex.from_product()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am trying to turn this dataframe Output1 into the Output2 below it.  I have attempted various methods but am stumped now.  The closest I got was using **pd.MultiIndex.from_product()** but am clearly not doing it correctly.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Output1:

Date        Name    Raised  Recvd   Donated
1/1/2020    John    18320   13374   6687
1/1/2020    Mary    2270    1044    522
1/1/2020    David   18086   9947    4974
2/1/2020    John    18806   7334    3667
2/1/2020    Mary    9350    7854    3927
2/1/2020    David   13009   8456    4228
3/1/2020    John    12597   6299    3149
3/1/2020    Mary    17277   7429    3715
3/1/2020    David   8894    2935    1468
4/1/2020    John    16068   13176   6588
4/1/2020    Mary    10666   6293    3146
4/1/2020    David   4559    2006    1003

Output2:

            John                    Mary                    David       
Date        Raised  Recvd   Donated Raised  Recvd   Donated Raised  Recvd   Donated
1/1/2020    18320   13374   6687    2270    1044    522     18086   9947    4974
2/1/2020    18806   7334    3667    9350    7854    3927    13009   8456    4228
3/1/2020    12597   6299    3149    17277   7429    3715    8894    2935    1468
4/1/2020    16068   13176   6588    10666   6293    3146    4559    2006    1003
```

Comment: does `df.pivot(index="Date", columns="Name")` not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.pivot(index=['Date'], columns=['Name'], values=None).swaplevel(axis=1).sort_values('Name', axis=1)

Name      David                 John                  Mary
         Raised Recvd Donated Raised  Recvd Donated Raised Recvd Donated
Date
1/1/2020  18086  9947    4974  18320  13374    6687   2270  1044     522
2/1/2020  13009  8456    4228  18806   7334    3667   9350  7854    3927
3/1/2020   8894  2935    1468  12597   6299    3149  17277  7429    3715
4/1/2020   4559  2006    1003  16068  13176    6588  10666  6293    3146
```